# C# Using span with SocketAsyncEventArgs

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-core, unsafe

I would like to use new Span to send unmanaged data straight to the socket using `SocketAsyncEventArgs` but it seems that `SocketAsyncEventArgs` can only accept `Memory<byte>` which cannot be initialized with `byte *` or `IntPt`r.

So please is there a way to do use span with `SocketAsyncEventArgs`?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can´t use Span with async methods, that´s what memory<T> is for. You don´t say how you hrt you unmsnsgrd data so it´s hard to help... There are Marshal functions that return a Memory<> that you could use.

Comment: I have a C code which returns guint8 *data; gsize size;

Comment: If you want to send unmanaged data "directly", then you don't want to use `SocketAsyncEventArgs`. The whole point of that class is to serve as a unit in a managed object pool, to cut down on allocations. It tries for the same goal as `Span`, but in a different way (at a time when `Span` did not yet exist). To blast unmanaged data directly to a socket, you'd need `Span`-enabled versions of the regular methods (and that's worked on [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/22988)), but that's not asynchronous -- and they can't be, due to the stack-based nature of `Span`.

Comment: It is, in theory, possible to build a new kind of `SocketAsyncEventArgs` infrastructure that can work with unmanaged memory -- you know, just because we don't have enough ways to interact with sockets yet. :-P I don't see that interoperating very well with the current `SocketAsyncEventArgs`, though.

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned in the comments, Span is the wrong tool here - have you looked at using [Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memory-1?view=netcore-2.1) instead? As you stated, the [`SetBuffer` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.setbuffer?view=netcore-2.1#System_Net_Sockets_SocketAsyncEventArgs_SetBuffer_System_Memory_System_Byte__) does accept that as a parameter - is there a reason you can't use it?

See also [this article](https://medium.com/@antao.almada/how-to-use-span-t-and-memory-t-c0b126aae652) for a good explanation on how stack vs heap allocation applies to Span and Memory. It includes this example, using a `readonly Memory<Foo> buffer`:

```
public struct Enumerable : IEnumerable<Foo>
{
    readonly Stream stream;

    public Enumerable(Stream stream)
    {
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    public IEnumerator<Foo> GetEnumerator() => new Enumerator(this);

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

    public struct Enumerator : IEnumerator<Foo>
    {
        static readonly int ItemSize = Unsafe.SizeOf<Foo>();

        readonly Stream stream;
        readonly Memory<Foo> buffer;
        bool lastBuffer;
        long loadedItems;
        int currentItem;

        public Enumerator(Enumerable enumerable)
        {
            stream = enumerable.stream;
            buffer = new Foo[100]; // alloc items buffer
            lastBuffer = false;
            loadedItems = 0;
            currentItem = -1;
        }

        public Foo Current => buffer.Span[currentItem];

        object IEnumerator.Current => Current;

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (++currentItem != loadedItems) // increment current position and check if reached end of buffer
                return true;
            if (lastBuffer) // check if it was the last buffer
                return false;

            // get next buffer
            var rawBuffer = MemoryMarshal.Cast<Foo, byte>(buffer);
            var bytesRead = stream.Read(rawBuffer);
            lastBuffer = bytesRead < rawBuffer.Length;
            currentItem = 0;
            loadedItems = bytesRead / ItemSize;
            return loadedItems != 0;
        }

        public void Reset() => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // nothing to do
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should copy the data to managed memory first, use Marshal or Buffer class.

If not think about when the C code delete the returned pointer what will happen to the send data?

Answer (score 0):

There's a complete example (and implementation of the class) on the MSDN page for the [SocketAsyncEventArgs (just follow the link)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs?view=netframework-4.7.2). It shows the proper use of the class and may give you the guidence you're looking for.

Also, as Shingo said, it should all be in managed code, not in pointers.